# Replacing string with variable, output to variably named files

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have the template file *12A-r.inp* . I want to prepare files from this file whose name will be *16A-r.inp*, *20A-r.inp*, *24A-r.inp*. And I want to change some parameter in those files according to their names. For example, I want to replace the string "*12A*" in all places in file *12A-r.inp*, with *16A* in *16A-r.inp*, and *20A* in *20A-r.inp*. I have written the code below for this:

```
for ((i=12;i<=24;i=i+4))
do
  cat 12A-r.inp >> $i\A-r.inp
done
for ((i=12;i<=24;i=i+4))
do
  sed -i "s/12A/${i}/g" $i\A-r.inp
done
```

But the problem is *12A* gets replaced by *${i}*, not with strings like *16A*, *20A* etc.

Comment: Can you try it again by copy-pasting the code from this post? Don't reuse the code you ran previously, make a new script by copy-pasting from your post into a new file. The problem you describe would happen if you used `'s/12A/${i}/g'` but you've posted double quotes and it should be fine.

Comment: I copied the code to a new file and ran, but 12A is replaced by ${i}  this time too.

Comment: Sorry, the code was not working as there was some problem in my input file. Now it worked. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: When `i=12`, the above code incorrectly doubles the template file, and every file based on it.  See [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45134578/6136214) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Observations:

1. In `for ((i=12;i<=24;i=i+4))` counts *12,16,20,24*.  There's no need
   to start at `12`, since the template is already correct.  Worse,
   when `i=12`, this code `cat 12A-r.inp >> $i\A-r.inp` *appends* a
   copy of the template file onto itself, doubling it, which causes *every* ensuing
   created file to be twice as long as the original template.
2. The `\` in `$i\A-r.inp` is unnecessary, since `A` is not a special character.
3. The `cat` is unnecessary, `sed` without `-i` can do it all.
4. In `sed`, `s/12A/${i}/g` would replace the string "*12**A***", with whatever number `$i` is, without the "***A***", unless the variable includes that letter.
5. The `for` loop uses a `bash`ism to enumerate `i`... in this instance there's a simpler equivalent `bash`ism, (see below).

Suggested revision:

```
for i in {16..24..4}A
do
  sed "s/12A/${i}/g" 12A-r.inp > ${i}-r.inp
done
```

How it works:

- `$i` is set to *16A,20A,* and *24A*.
- `sed` repeatedly reads in the template, replaces *12A* with `$i`,
  prints everything to *STDOUT*...
- which is redirected to the appropriately named file.